# determine whether $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sin(na + b) = c$ if and only if $\sin a = 0,\sin b = c$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

> Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}.$ Prove or disprove the following $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sin(na + b) = c$ if and only if $\sin a = 0,\sin b = c$. If false, state which direction (converse or the forward implication) holds or if no direction holds.

By the definition of a limit, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sin(na + b) = c$ if and only if for all $\epsilon > 0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that for $n \ge N, |\sin(na+b) -c| <\epsilon.$ Assume $\sin a = 0, \sin b = c.$ Then $a = k\pi$ for some integer $k.$ Hence for each $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+, \sin(na + b) = \sin(nk\pi)\cos(b) + \sin(b)\cos(nk\pi) = (-1)^{nk\pi}\sin(b),$ which clearly diverges if $nk$ is odd. This seems wrong though.

Now suppose $\sin a \neq 0$. Assume first that $a > 0.$ I need to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sin(na + b) \neq c$, however I'm not sure how I can do so. $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \sin(k) = c,$ where $k = na+b,$ but this is a contradiction because the values $\sin(\lceil \frac{k}{2\pi}  \rceil 2\pi \pm \frac{\pi}2)$ are always at least $2$ apart and get arbitrarily large.  One can obtain a similar contradiction if $a < 0.$ So $\sin a = 0$ and hence $\sin (b)=c.$

> Am I missing something?

Comment: So it looks like your reasoning is leading towards a "false" answer: in the case $a = \pi$, $b = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $c=1$, you have $\sin a = 0 \land \sin b = c$ but you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(na+b) = c$.

Comment: So is that false answer what it should be?